# Changing Event Handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following scenario: My application has a compiler that works correctly. The user chooses a control on the screen and write code in C # for this control. Before recording in the database, the user has the option to want if this event occurs before the code already written for the control or if the code you have written will have priority over the system code. My actual code:

```
public void ExecutaCodigo (string codigo)
{
    ExecuteSnippetUser(codigo);
}

public void AtribuiEvento(Control c, string evento, string codigo, bool prioritario)
{
    evento = evento.ToLower();
    if(evento == "click")
    {
        if (!prioritario)
        {
            c.Click += delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ExecuteSnippetUser(codigo);
                    // works fine!!! application and after, user code
            };
        }
        else
        {   
            c.Click -= delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            };
            c.Click += delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ExecuteSnippetUser(codigo);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you have to unbind the same instance.

Comment: also, please don't use snippets for c#.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to hold onto a reference to the handler that you used to be able to remove it:

```
private ClickEventHandler handler;
public void AtribuiEvento(Control c, string evento, string codigo, bool prioritario)
{
    evento = evento.ToLower();
    if(evento == "click")
    {
        c.Click -= handler;
        handler = delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExecuteSnippetUser(codigo);
        };
        c.Click += handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: The statement "private ClickEventHandler handler" was not possible to implement. I'm developing in WinForms traditional @Servy

Comment: Then use the actual type of that delegate.  I'm sure you can figure out what that event's actual delegate is.